# How is it possible to instantiate from a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Q1) How is this possible?!

```
function employer(name) { this.name = name;};

var fred = new employer('Fred');
```

Isn't employer a function rather than a class?

Q2) What does

```
employer.prototype
```

signify?

and finally

Q3) How does this work?

```
employer.prototype.salary = null;
fred.salary = 2000;
```

Can someone please give simple explanation? Please :)

Comment: Read this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript :D

Comment: Can you not search for Javascript OO topics on your own? Pretty much any basic tutorial should cover all of your questions.

Comment: Why are you putting 3 questions in 1 instead of creating 3 separate questions?

Comment: @RaYell: Sorry man, out of excitement :-)

Comment: Seriously? We're complaining that people are asking questions on a Q&A site now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you asked for a simple explanation, here we go:

Q1) This is possible because JavaScript functions are first-class (i.e. they are objects, and you can create `new` objects).

Q2) A `prototype` is an object from which other objects inherit properties. Properties of an objects prototype will be available to all instances of that object.

Q3) This means that all instances of `employer` will have a property `salary` with the value `null`. The instance of `employer` called `fred` simply overrides that initial `null` value with `2000`. It's the same `salary` property though (when you use a property, the scope chain is searched until a match is found. In this case, a match is found on the object prototype).

Quick example:

```
function employer(name) { this.name = name;};
employer.prototype.salary = 1000;

var fred = new employer('Fred');
var jim = new employer('Jim');

console.log(fred.salary) //Prints 1000 because employer.prototype.salary == 1000
fred.salary = 2000;
console.log(fred.salary) //Prints 2000 because fred's salary has been changed
console.log(jim.salary) //Prints 1000 because jim's salary is still referencing the prototype

fred.age = 30;
console.log(fred.age) //Prints 30
console.log(jim.age) //Prints undefined (age is a property of fred, not employer.prototype
```